# Microsoft Access - Create email and programmatically click "Sign" button

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I'm trying to generate some automated emails in MS Access and I need to sign the email before sending it. I'd like to do it programmatically but I'm running into issues trying to execute the ribbon button "Sign"

Here's my sub that sends the email

```
Public Sub SendEmail(ByRef sTo As String, ByRef sSubject As String, ByRef sBody As String, Optional sOnBehalfOf As String = "", Optional sCc As String = "", Optional sBcc As String = "")
    Dim bHtml As Boolean
    If (InStr(1, sBody, "<b>") Or InStr(1, sBody, "<font>") Or InStr(1, sBody, "<td>") Or InStr(1, sBody, "<br>")) Then bHtml = True

    With Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = sOnBehalfOf
        .To = sTo
        .CC = sCc
        .BCC = sBcc
        .Subject = sSubject
        If (bHtml) Then
            .HTMLBody = sBody
        Else
            .Body = sBody
        End If
        .Display
        SendKeys ("^{Enter}")
    End With
End Sub
```

After .Display I need to click the "Sign" button on the newly created email and then SendKeys("^{Enter}"). I need to programmatically click "Sign" because the email has hyperlinks and is formatted in html.

Edit: By sign I mean the "Sign" button that will digitally sign the email

Comment: I'd reccomend not using sendKeys - its dangerous and can have inconsistent results

Comment: The .Send method does not work, I think it has something to do with a permissions issue on my work computer. Unless there is a way to also programmatically click the "Send" button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` property. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2009/03/16/how-to-sign-or-encrypt-a-message-programmatically-from-oom/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried using this but could not get it to work. Kept getting some method error.
    Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, 2

Comment: ActiveInspector was not a method of Application. So I changed it to Outlook.Application and get the error "Object or With block variable not set"

Comment: Is your script running in Access VBA? In that case Application intrinsic variable refers to Access. You need to explicitly create an instance of the Outlook.Application object using CreateObject and use that object instead.

Comment: That's why I was using Outlook.Application and I have Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library in my references (Tools -> References)

Comment: But your code never **creates** a new instance of the Outlook.Application object. Your code above will not even run

Comment: set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Comment: set msg = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)